# Regex expression for decimal number with dot and whitespace

Tags: c#, regex

Can someone help me find a Regex expression in c# to check if the line starts with decimal number, dot and a whitespace?

```
"1. "
"24. "
"42.5. "
"2000.18. "
"35401.5. "
```

I've tried with:

```
^\d+\.+ 
^[1-9]*([1-9]|0)?(\.[0-9]+)
[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]
```

Comment: The first regex works for some of your inputs. Did you determine why it doesn't work on the others?

Comment: Test your regex with http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ You can verify your regex on the fly on your input.

Answer (score 1):

> Check if the line starts with decimal number, dot and a whitespace

```
 ^\d+(\.\d+)?\.\s
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`^\d+(\.\d+)?\.\s`

or, if `".1"` classifies as a decimal number:

`^\d*\.?\d+\.\s`

or, if `"1."` classifies as a decimal number:

`^\d+\.?\d*\.\s`

or, if both `".1"` and `"1."` classify as decimal numbers:

`^(\d+\.?|\d*\.\d+)\.\s`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
^\d+(\.\d+)?\.\s$
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, try:

```
   (\d+\.\s)$
```